# How to display a calendar instead of textinput to have the date with REACT?

Tags: reactjs

how can I do to have a calendar instead of having a textinput in my form please ??

```
export default function InterviewSettings() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState("");
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");    
  ...    
  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Date:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={date}
            placeholder="DD/MM/YY"
            onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change the input type from `type="text"` to HTML5 date type `type="date"`, this should do the trick.

Comment: if i put type='date' the language is not in english. Is there a way to choose the language please

Comment: I have tried at my end and working fine and the language is English. You might have a different problem for language. Can you check your "index.html" file inside the public folder for this <html lang="en">?

Comment: Yes I got <html lang="en">

Comment: consider voting up if this works for you, thanks

Comment: the language is not english is it normal although I have <html lang="en">?

Comment: there may be some other issue with the language

Answer (score 0):

Tou can use [input type="date"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

```html
<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
       value="2018-07-22"
       min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31">
```

or you can consider 3-rd party libraries for that:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dates